# Insert GridView Cells or Data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am looking for a way to insert all of my GridView Cells or data into a SQL Server Table.  I want the columns to match the columns of SQL Server and each row to be added.  The rows change all the time.  Is this possible?

Here is what I have tried (no errors, just doesn't do anything)

```
        foreach (GridViewRow GVRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            string PartNumber = string.Empty;
            string Qty = string.Empty;
            string Price = string.Empty;
            string ExtPrice = string.Empty;

            PartNumber = GVRow.Cells[1].Text;
            Qty = GVRow.Cells[2].Text;
            Price = GVRow.Cells[3].Text;
            ExtPrice = GVRow.Cells[4].Text;



            using (SqlConnection sqlCon5 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand();
                scm.Connection = sqlCon5;
                scm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO OrderDetail (OrderNumber, PartNumber, Qty, Price, ExtPrice) VALUES (@OrderNumber, @PartNumber,@Qty,@Price,@ExtPrice)";

                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", TextBox1.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", PartNumber.ToString());
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty.ToString());
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price.ToString());
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtPrice", ExtPrice.ToString());


                sqlCon5.Open();
                scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon5.Close();
            }



        }
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried?

Comment: I just added my code that i have tried, but it does not work it doesn't do anything @bigodera

Comment: Does not do anything? Does it reach the first `foreach`? Yes? What line does it get to?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for loop` instead.

```
int rowsCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
int rowsInserted = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
{
    StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO OrderDetail (OrderNumber, PartNumber, Qty, Price, ExtPrice) VALUES   (@OrderNumber, @PartNumber,@Qty,@Price,@ExtPrice)";
    scm.CommandText = StrQuery;
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber",GridView1.Rows[i].
                      Cells["columnName"].Value);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber",GridView1.Rows[i].
                      Cells["columnName"].Value);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty",GridView1.Rows[i].
                      Cells["columnName"].Value);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",GridView1.Rows[i].
                      Cells["columnName"].Value);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtPrice",GridView1.Rows[i].
                      Cells["columnName"].Value);

if (scm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    rowsInserted++;
}
scm.Parameters.Clear();
}

//check if all rows inserted
if(rowsCount == rowsInserted)
{
   //Display successfull message
}
else
{
  //Display error message
}
```

NOTE* replace `columnName` with the actual column name from `GridView1`.

Comment: I am getting invalid arguments on where you enter the columnname